How to switch to the 1st 2nd or 3rd app with specific name? (all 3 have the same name)
NOT three windows of one app, I use Neohub which launches instances of the Neovide app, which can't have multiple windows. There are 3 instances of Neovide on my dock, and it shows 3 times in Activity Monitor. I want 3 hotkeys to switch to the 1st 2nd or 3rd instance. I asked an LLM for an AppleScript to do so and this is what it came up with, but it doesn't work when I changes the number 2 to a 1 or 3.
-- Define the search string
set searchString to "Neovide"

-- Get the list of running applications
tell application "System Events"
    set appList to name of every application process
end tell

-- Filter the list to find applications whose names contain the search string
set matchingApps to {}
repeat with appName in appList
    if appName contains searchString then
        copy appName to the end of the matchingApps
    end if
end repeat

-- Get the second matching application
set secondApp to item 2 of matchingApps
-- Switch to the second matching application
tell application secondApp
    activate
end tell


Your approach cannot work because all running instances of the application have the same name. The following solution is inspired by this answer and uses process identifiers (not to be confused with the “Unix process identifier”, which is unix id in AppleScript):
set searchString to "Neovide"
set theIndex to 2

tell application "System Events"
    try
        set theId to id of process theIndex whose name is searchString
        set frontmost of process id theId to true
    end try
end tell

That worked well in my test.

I edited the other answer to toggle the window rather than just show it.
set searchString to "Neovide"
set theIndex to 2

tell application "System Events"
    try
        set theId to id of process theIndex whose name is searchString
        if frontmost of process id theId then
            set visible of process id theId to false
        else
            set frontmost of process id theId to true
        end if
    end try
end tell


This would work much better as an edit for the answer provided that has got a few up votes…
